ACF Diagnostic for Shifted Distribution Univariate Time Series Data
I have these 1920 observations with shifted distribution. For some reasons I want to use all of observations for time series modeling but I have difficulty in reading the ACF plot. I need detail explaination if there any seasonal or long-term dependency from ACF plot, which lags do I have to pointed out, or is there any specific characteristic pattern.



Welcome to CV, Aulia.  could you please explain what you mean by "shifted distribution"?  Have you reviewed our posts on interpreting ACF plots?

@whuber  what I mean in the distribution shift there is a difference in the average point in the period and the unstable variance, the maximum point of the data also changes because there is a long-term trend around 2022 to 2024, which also causes non-stationarity. Thanks for the suggestion. But the acf plot in my data is decreasing very slowly at each lag. I haven't found any explanation with a similar acf plot. Should I differencing the data first? I'm sorry i'm not native in english

Please add new info as an edit to the post, not only as comments. Comments on this site are ephemeral, often seen by vert few, and can be deleted
